# Timeago not working in ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, timeago, abbr

I an using [this](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/) plugin for calculate timeago, it is not working when i load content by ajax call.

I have created 2 fiddle for this,Please check [`working fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/hemc/y3xFr/1/) 
and [`not working fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/hemc/eJhAr/11/)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `html` param in your post data is a mess:

```
html: "<abbr title="2013-06-21T12:57:04+0530" class="timeago">
        2013-06-21 12:57:04
    </abbr>"."<abbr title="2013-06-22T11:17:26+0530" class="timeago">
    2013-06-22 11:17:26
</abbr>",
```

should be:

```
html: "<abbr title=\"2013-06-21T12:57:04+0530\" class=\"timeago\">2013-06-21 12:57:04</abbr>"+"<abbr title=\"2013-06-22T11:17:26+0530\" class=\"timeago\">2013-06-22 11:17:26</abbr>"
```

You are using quotes to encase your html string, but not escaping the quotes used in the html itself - and it appears you were trying to use a `.` to concat the string, in javascript you should use a `+`.

Though, the formatting is weird after that fix, it works.

Comment: @Hemc no problem - make sure to find and fix that `.` instead of `+` or remove it completely if it was unintended.  I don't think karthikr caught that one. :)

Comment: @kmfk Nice catch. I missed that. Guess it was working because it was part of the same string. Fiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/eJhAr/14/